Hide tab bar when keyboard opens on android devices
I'm trying to hide the tab bar when the keyboard is open. It hides automatically on iOS, but not on Android:
screenOptions={{ tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true, ... }}

The solution is to add this "softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "pan" in android object :
"android": {
    "package": "com.imad.imad",
    "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/images/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "pan"
    }

